# How to display a downloaded image through url path

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7, firebase-storage

[image]I am using firebase 3.0 in my app and i have succesfully downloaded the image to a particular filepath, but

```
if let downloadedImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: filePath){
                self.profilePictureImageView.image = downloadedImage
                print("displayed")
            }
```

this code doesnt execute beacause its giving nil,and my filePath is

`file:/Users/achintyagupta/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A9F47009-5CB5-4DCE-AB9D-7D8C68F0CAD9/data/Containers/Data/Application/90AA4BDB-0301-48FE-948C-56A33966424A/Documents/96MDsdewjLOW0KbC6Gd9Vi56yPm1.jpg`

Actual filePath of the image

Comment: `filePath` may not have "file:" at the beginning. How did you get it? Note that the UUID may change.

Comment: i printed the filepath

Comment: @Larme i have updated the post, also tried putting MacintoshHD in place of files:/ , didnt work!

Comment: no worries figured out!

Comment: Giving the reason of your error and the way you fixed it (maybe a link to another question) could help other users who face the same issue.

Comment: Actually it was your solution, in one part of the code 'storagePath' needed filePath to have 'file:/' String in it but while catching the file through url in it didn't need that. `if let downloadedImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: filePath)` it didn't. I went to `Terminal` drag and dropped the file got the actual path and then changed the filePath for UIImage accordingly.

Comment: I have posted my uploading and downloading code here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37510771/downloading-image-on-swift-2-form-firebase-storage/38228231#38228231

Comment: @Larme Thanks btw  :-)